# can you help me for limit my command (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i want to ask you how I can DM people with a bot for the new of my server because i have a command but its send to much DM like 20

script:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.content === "!dm"){
        if(message.deletable) message.delete();
        i = 0;
        message.guild.members.forEach(member => {

        if(i < 1){
          var interval = setInterval (function () {
            member.send(` message`).catch(e => {});
          }, 50)

          }   
      })
    }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend using async await instead of setTimeout as you have a better control over the flow of the code. Try this code:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.content === "!dm"){
    if(message.deletable) message.delete();
    let count = 0; 
    message.guild.members.cache.forEach(async mem => {
      if(count < 5){ /*this is your users limit. Change it as per your need*/
        await mem.send("the messasge").catch(console.error);
        count++;
      }else{
        return;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: when i use your command its write 

Program path uses differently cased character as file on disk; this might result in breakpoints not being hit.
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --inspect-brk=46088 '"self bot ash\raid.js"'